# A link only after the second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

It is necessary not to follow the link on the first click and resolve only after the second . I wrote code :

```
$(".categoriesPage .categoryBox .textBox").attr("data-count", "0");
$(".categoriesPage .categoryBox .textBox").on("click", function(){
    $(this).each(function() {
        var clickCount = $(this).attr("data-count");
        clickCount ++;
        if (clickCount == 1) {
            $(this).attr("dataCount", clickCount);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

It does not work , the error may be what ?

Comment: Shouldn't `$(this).attr("dataCount", clickCount);` be `$(this).attr("data-count", clickCount);`? And do you really need the `.each()`? https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sqxwdn6y/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".categoriesPage .categoryBox .textBox").attr("data-count", "0");
    $(".categoriesPage .categoryBox .textBox").on("click", function() {
        var clickCount = $(this).attr("data-count");
        clickCount++;
        if (clickCount == 1) {
            $(".categoriesPage .categoryBox .textBox[data-count='1']").attr("data-count", "0");
            $(this).attr("data-count", clickCount);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
```